# wordpress two column responsive layout

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to have a two column layout in wordpress? I've been trying to build it with css using float:left; but I can't seem to get it to work inside the loop :(

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: That's quite a vague question. The answer to both is "Yes", but I've got a feeling you want more out of this... What exactly are you trying to achieve with the two columns?

Comment: You'd probably also be better off posting it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which is the StackExchange website for Wordpress questions.

Comment: I want to display posts side by side as opposed to the other way but unsure as to how the loop would work with the css.

Comment: One alternate iterations of the loop give it a div round the post with a class of left or right..?

Comment: did try that but the loop was halving the percentage each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, listing the posts in this order -

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

However, if you want as below, then some tweaking will be required -

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Here is the PHP -

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Enter whatever code you want for your display here -->
    </div>

    <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php if($i % 2 === 0) : ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

And some basic CSS (change as required if the selector `.post` is too generic) -

```
.post{
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```